# The formula $P = 1,527,000 (1.015)^t$ gives the population $t$ years after 2008. Find the population in 2009 and 2010?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

The formula $P = 1,527,000 (1.015)^t$ gives the population $t$ years after 2008. Find the population in

(a) 2009

(b) 2010

What is the answer and a proper solution to this problem?

This is all about logarithmic and exponential functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple substitution

In 2009 one year has passed, so put $t=1$ into your equation, and for 2010 there have been $2$ years, so put $t=2$ in.

Comment: Awww thank you. So I just substitute t=1 in the equation (a) 2001? Like that?

Comment: @AnicaLanaPiando Your part (a) says 2009. So you find the difference between 2008 and 2009, which is $1$. If you were doing 2001 you would have to put in $-7$

Comment: THANK YOU so muchh❤️